# Only One ADC but many Channels

Tags: converters, digital, adc, channel, analog-digital-converter

If it is given in a Datasheet for a ARM Processor :

**1×12-bit, 2.4 MSPS A/D converter: up to 16 channels**

Is it only one ADC with 16 Channels and.
Have all of them 2.4 MSPS or need they to share the speed?

Thank you!!

Comment: http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1577/LN1877/PF260049?s_searchtype=keyword

Comment: This is where i found this Data

Answer (score 0):

They share the speed. Generally you can set them up in continuous mode and they will be sampled one after each other by the same adc. Although to get more accuracy you might have to introduce a delay (in cycles) between sampling so this will further reduce the number samples per second.